# Thrift: Is it possible to do only serialization with the C (GLib) Thrift library?

Tags: c, serialization, thrift

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/c_glib/test/testserialization.c) example but it always return write_len = 10 bytes.

```
ThriftTransport* transport = THRIFT_TRANSPORT(
    g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER, "buf_size", 8096, NULL));
ThriftProtocol* protocol = THRIFT_PROTOCOL(
    g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_BINARY_PROTOCOL, "transport", transport,
        NULL));

Exception* src = g_object_new(TYPE_EXCEPTION, NULL);
ExceptionClass* cls = EXCEPTION_GET_CLASS(src);
g_object_set(src,
    "ex_sign", exception_signature,
    "cl_sign", class_signature,
    "caught", catch_method != NULL,
    NULL);

int write_len = THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(cls)->write(THRIFT_STRUCT(src), protocol, &error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug in the C (GLib) implementation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3455) that was reported and fixed just recently, so you'll need to fetch and build [the latest Thrift source](http://thrift.apache.org/developers#source-control) from git for the example to work correctly.

If you're curious, you can see [the discussion on the user mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201511.mbox/%3C1448492604.6423%40zygmund.net%3E) that led to the bug being identified.

Comment: Thank you! Will try tomorrow with the latest source

Answer (score 1):

After some research and with the help of community I came up with serializing solution that works not only with master branch, but with 0.9.3 version as well. Actually we don't need variable write_len at all:

```
ThriftMemoryBuffer* tbuffer = g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER,
    "buf_size", 2048, NULL);
ThriftTransport *transport = NULL;
ThriftProtocol* protocol = NULL;
GError* error = NULL;

if (tbuffer) {
    transport = THRIFT_TRANSPORT(tbuffer);
    thrift_transport_open(transport, &error);

    protocol =
    THRIFT_PROTOCOL(
        g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_BINARY_PROTOCOL, "transport", transport, NULL));

    if (protocol) {
        ExceptionData* exception_data = g_object_new(TYPE_EXCEPTION_DATA, "ex_sign",
            exception_signature, "cl_sign", class_signature, "caught",
            catch_method != NULL,
            NULL);

        if (exception_data) {
            ThriftStructClass* cls = THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(EXCEPTION_DATA_GET_CLASS(exception_data));
            cls->write(exception_data, protocol, &error);

            if(tbuffer->buf != NULL) {

                printf("Buffer length %i bytes\n", tbuffer->buf->len);

                send_kafka_message((const void *)tbuffer->buf->data, tbuffer->buf->len);
            }

            g_object_unref(exception_data);
        }

        g_object_unref(protocol);
    }

    if (thrift_transport_is_open(transport)) {
        thrift_transport_close(transport, &error);
    }

    g_object_unref(tbuffer);
}
```