# Apache Thrift C GLib -> Java deserialization issue

Tags: java, c, serialization, deserialization, thrift

I can't deserialize in Java Thrift object that have been serialized using C GLib.
My serialization code is the following (solution that I came up with after my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357173/4445238)):

```
ThriftMemoryBuffer* tbuffer = g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER,
    "buf_size", 2048, NULL);
ThriftTransport *transport = NULL;
ThriftProtocol* protocol = NULL;
GError* error = NULL;

if (tbuffer) {
    transport = THRIFT_TRANSPORT(tbuffer);
    thrift_transport_open(transport, &error);

    protocol =
    THRIFT_PROTOCOL(
        g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_BINARY_PROTOCOL, "transport", transport, NULL));

    if (protocol) {
        ExceptionData* exception_data = g_object_new(TYPE_EXCEPTION_DATA, "ex_sign",
            exception_signature, "cl_sign", class_signature, "caught",
            catch_method != NULL,
            NULL);

        if (exception_data) {
            ThriftStructClass* cls = THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(EXCEPTION_DATA_GET_CLASS(exception_data));
            int write_len = cls->write(exception_data, protocol, &error);

            if(tbuffer->buf != NULL) {

                printf("Write len %i bytes\n", write_len);
                printf("Data sending: %s, %s, %b \n", exception_data->ex_sign, exception_data->cl_sign, exception_data->caught);

                send_kafka_message((const void *)tbuffer->buf, write_len);
            }

            g_object_unref(exception_data);
        }

        g_object_unref(protocol);
    }

    if (thrift_transport_is_open(transport)) {
        thrift_transport_close(transport, &error);
    }

    g_object_unref(tbuffer);
}
```

Deserialization code in Java:

```
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer();
ExceptionData ex = new ExceptionData();

try {
    byte[] binData = tuple.getBinary(0);

    _logger.info("Bin data length: " + binData.length);
    _logger.info("HEX data: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(binData));

    deserializer.deserialize(ex, binData);
} catch (TException e) {
    _logger.error(e);
}

_logger.info("Deserialized object: " + ex);
```

And it always fails with exception similar to:

```
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'caught' was not found in serialized data!
```

My Thrift scheme is:

```
struct ExceptionData {
    1: required string ex_sign, // exception signature
    2: required string cl_sign, // class signature where exception was thrown
    3: required bool caught // whether exception was caught or not
}
```

The length of sent and received message are the same. But somehow on Java side I cant reproduce object.

May be someone has faced similar issue?

UPD:

Sample outputs:

```
ExceptionData("Ljava/lang/ClassNotFoundException;", "Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;", true)
HEX data: 40890DE0297F00004C000000800000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007E0DE0297F00000100000000000000000000000000000090D900E0
HEX data(1): 00880D109D7F00004E000000800000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007E0D109D7F000001000000000000000000000000000000507F0D109D7F
HEX data(2): 00880D4CF57F00004E000000800000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007E0D4CF57F000001000000000000000000000000000000507F0D4CF57F
```

I noticed some weird things with the outputs above:

1. Why for the same input data it serializes into different outputs?
2. Why is so many zeroes?

I tried serialize-deserialize the same object **using Java only** and this is sample output:

```
ExceptionData("Ljava/lang/ClassNotFoundException;", "Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;", true)
HEX data: 0B0001000000224C6A6176612F6C616E672F436C6173734E6F74466F756E64457863657074696F6E3B0B0002000000194C6A6176612F6E65742F55524C436C6173734C6F616465723B0200030100
```

If I use Java only objects serialize-deserialize correctly and HEX output is the same for same input data

UPD2:

Made two successive hex dumps of the same tbuffer->buf before sending to kafka. Looks like buffer contains wrong data before sending:

```
call 1 buf:
  0000  00 88 0d 2c ce 7f 00 00 4e 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  ...,....N.......
  0010  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0030  00 7e 0d 2c ce 7f 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .~.,............
  0040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 e2 00 2c ce 7f        ........P..,..


call 2 buf:
  0000  80 88 0d b8 08 7f 00 00 4e 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  ........N.......
  0010  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0030  00 e1 00 b8 08 7f 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 88 0d b8 08 7f        ........ .....
```

Comment: The fields are all marked `required`. Aside from the question whether that is a good decision or not, `required` means líterally that: The field **must** be present in the data stream to be deserialized. Most implementations check the presence of `required` members before and after de/serialization, and that's what you see here.

Comment: Can we see a data sample? The hex values that are printed maybe?

Comment: Added sample outputs and some comments in the question (after UPD)

Comment: Indeed. The first data BLOBs (those with the many zeros) are utterly wrong. Either something has gone wrong during transmission of the buffer content from C/glib to Java, or the buffer contents itself is wrong from the start. The data look like some deserialized memory with some pointers in it, so at some point there is probably either a pointer dereference missing, or an address operator. Or sth. like that.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that. Added hex dumps of buffer right after serialization on client side (UPD2)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found where was the mistake. Serialized data stores in **tbuffer->buf->data** instead of tbuffer->buf. And the buffer lenght stores in **tbuffer->buf->len**.

So, the final working code is:

```
ThriftMemoryBuffer* tbuffer = g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER,
    "buf_size", 2048, NULL);
ThriftTransport *transport = NULL;
ThriftProtocol* protocol = NULL;
GError* error = NULL;

if (tbuffer) {
    transport = THRIFT_TRANSPORT(tbuffer);
    thrift_transport_open(transport, &error);

    protocol =
    THRIFT_PROTOCOL(
        g_object_new(THRIFT_TYPE_BINARY_PROTOCOL, "transport", transport, NULL));

    if (protocol) {
        ExceptionData* exception_data = g_object_new(TYPE_EXCEPTION_DATA, "ex_sign",
            exception_signature, "cl_sign", class_signature, "caught",
            catch_method != NULL,
            NULL);

        if (exception_data) {
            ThriftStructClass* cls = THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(EXCEPTION_DATA_GET_CLASS(exception_data));
            cls->write(exception_data, protocol, &error);

            if(tbuffer->buf != NULL) {

                printf("Buffer length %i bytes\n", tbuffer->buf->len);

                send_kafka_message((const void *)tbuffer->buf->data, tbuffer->buf->len);
            }

            g_object_unref(exception_data);
        }

        g_object_unref(protocol);
    }

    if (thrift_transport_is_open(transport)) {
        thrift_transport_close(transport, &error);
    }

    g_object_unref(tbuffer);
}
```

Comment: Hi, trying to use c_lib I realized there's little documentation available. How did you find out how to use the library, if I might ask?